# I moved the AppData folder, now the start menu and notifications menu isn't working. I have no idea why

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, appdata

I moved my AppData folder to my second drive to save space, and the system icons on my taskbar, including the system menu and networking menu, won't work anymore. I can't right click on applications on the taskbar either.

I have a tiny SSD containing my windows installation, user, etc. The drive is only 118 gigabytes, and my AppData folder alone was 34.1 gigabytes. I obviously had to move it for my system to have space. I created a separate account with admin privileges, moved it to my second, much larger drive, and made a junction using the command prompt. Now, the system icons on my taskbar don't work. I could just move the folder back, but then I would run out of space almost immediately.

(More detailed process of what I did)

I made a secondary account with admin privileges on my main account. I copied the whole AppData folder, including the Local, LocalLow, and Roaming folders, to D:\AppData. I then made a junction using the following command:

```
mklink /j "C:\Users\(my username)\AppData" "D:\AppData"
```

I then restarted my computer.

Comment: How did you 'move' it? If you just literally copied it to the second drive & erased the original, then yes, you'll have to move it back & hope you get away with it. Then research how to do it properly. Alternatively buy a bigger drive. You can get 1TB these days for the price of the same size HD 5 years ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin It would be a large hassle to move all the files over, and several websites stated that I should move the AppData folder and make a junction to the new folder in command prompt using mklink /j.

Comment: If I can't find a good answer soon, I'll just move Local and LocalLow back to the original locations and make a junction to the roaming folder, which takes up most of the space.

Comment: You need to detail what you actually did in your question, along with any error messages etc.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages. It just doesn't work.

Comment: … & you're still adding details in comments. Please add your exact method to your question.

Comment: You're not supposed to move the appdata folder to a different hard drive. It's supposed to be on the same hard drive that windows is running from.